# Leer archivos en subcarpetas con bash

Tags: bash

Generé un pequeño script para leer diez mil (10.000) archivos separados en diez mil carpetas. Hago la prueba dentro de una carpeta y los comandos funcionan. Sin embargo, cuando intento aplicar a todas las carpetas no funciona.

¿Qué puede ser el error si cuando genero un archivo `.txt` con este comando parece leer todos los archivos?

Prueba:

```
find $PATH1 -maxdepth 2 -type f > leyendo_subcaretas.txt
```

Lo que intento hacer:

```
PATH1='/home/mar/Documents'
echo "Leer archivos..."
find $PATH1 -maxdepth 2 -type f | for file in *.nc; 
do
gmt grd2xyz $file -R110/130/40/50 -fig -fog  | gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' > $(basename $file .nc).dat
done
```

Además ¿cómo hago para que se guarden los nuevos archivos en la misma carpeta o bien con el nombre de la carpeta, ya que al tener nombres iguales está sobrescribiendo cada archivo en la carpeta donde está ubicado el script.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que pasas la salida estándar del `find` a un bucle `for` que no hace uso de ella porque busca los archivos con extensión `*.nc` en el directorio de trabajo, por lo que simplemente se ignora completamente el trabajo del `find`.

Para solucionar el problema deberías leer uno a uno los archivos encontrados por `find` usando, por ejemplo, la instrucción `read`:

```
PATH1='/home/mar/Documents'
echo "Leer archivos..."
find "$PATH1" -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.nc" | while read -r file
do
    gmt grd2xyz "$file" -R110/130/40/50 -fig -fog | \
        gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' > $(basename "$file" .nc).dat
done
```

PD: He agregado comillas en varios puntos de tu código para evitar que nombres de archivos con espacios en blanco rompan la estructura de las instrucciones preparadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda. @SergioRivas, con el for me generó algunos erroes como: "find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments."  Por ahora usé la sugerencia de Cuauhtli

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda. He editado mi respuesta para agregar la búsqueda de archivos que coincidan únicamente con el patrón que usabas en tu `for`, no caí antes en el motivo por el que querías usar aquél `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes prescindir del ciclo for

```
PATH1='/home/mar/Documents'
echo "Leer archivos..."

find $PATH1 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.nc" \
    | xargs -I {} bash -c 'gmt grd2xyz {} -R110/130/40/50 -fig -fog  | awk "{print \$1, \$2, \$3}" > $(basename {} .nc).dat'
```

Tal vez, no sé si entiendo bien tu planteamiento, podrías variar el parámetro de `-maxdepth 2` para que incluya más subcarpetas

**Nota: No lo he probado.**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
PATH1='/home/mar/Documents'
echo "Leer archivos..."
for i in $(find $PATH1 -name '*.nc' -maxdepth 2 -type f); do
    gmt grd2xyz $file -R110/130/40/50 -fig -fog  | gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' > $(basename $file .nc).dat
done
```

Comment: sería bueno indicar en qué mejora el código del AP, así como explicar el código en sí. Fíjate que la otra respuesta sugiere prescindir del bucle _for_

Comment: @Cuauhtli gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió también, pero otra consulta ¿cómo hago para que se guarden los nuevos archivos en la misma carpeta o bien con el nombre de la carpeta, ya que al tener nombres iguales está sobreescribiendo el archivo. Gracias,